# Difference bwtween oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXADataSource and oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource

Tags: java, oracle, database-connection

What is difference b/w **`oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXADataSource`** and **`oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource`** ,I know both are XA-Complient but why two version exist?

I have gone through the docs 
[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/xa/client/OracleXADataSource.html) ,and It says

> For optimization purposes, we implemented 2 versions of
>   OracleXADataSource: one for client, and one for server when used in
>   Java Stored Procedures and in EJB

. what does the line **when used in Java Stored Procedures and in EJB** mean here ?

Comment: Did you examine the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/xa/client/OracleXADataSource.html)?

Comment: Yes I examine but i need clear understanding what benefit I will get by which ?

Comment: Did you read the description in the page I linked? It explains why this class exists.

Comment: Everything is not given in docs and i need more to to understand it clearly

Comment: reason for downvote ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that you can code Stored procedures in Oracle database not only with PL/SQL. You can write Java code inside Oracle database. But JavaDoc also says about EJB and it is unclear point. It seems `oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXADataSource` should be used in OC4J environment and inside Oracle database Stored procedures written in Java. In all other cases (other application servers and simple Java programs you should use `oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource`.

There is [another point in JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/xa/client/package-summary.html):

> Package **oracle.jdbc.xa.client** Description
>
> These should be used **outside the Oracle RDBMS.**

Comment: by stored procedure you mean Java stored procedure ?

Comment: It is still unclear to me in context of `oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXADataSource`

Comment: Stored procedure is **inner database object**, written in SQL. But sometimes they can be written in Java for Oracle RDBMS and in .Net in Ms SQL Server. In such **database internal** java code Oracle recommends you to use `oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXADataSource` insteand of  `oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource`

Comment: You mean I can write code that use JTA in oracle database

Comment: I mean you can use `oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXADataSource` in oracle database whichever way.

Comment: I need an example if you can provide to me